# Find file, check size and overwrite when filesize is different

Tags: shell-script, files, file-copy, xargs

Today I found a little bug in my own written CMS.
Now I want to rewrite all the files on the server with the same filename.
However, I do have some customers with the specific file customized so I can't overwrite all of the files.

Since some customers have a customized file, I need to check the filesize.

When the filesize is different than it's source, it should overwrite.
When it's the same filesize, it should skip the file.

A couple of months ago I asked a question a little similar, how-to overwrite multiple files from 1 source. I managed too fix this with:

```
echo /home/*/*/phpthumb | xargs -t -n 1 cp -r /home/test/testuser/phpthumb/*
```

Can I use this in a .sh script with a small if / else for rewriting or skipping the file?
If yes, how can I accomplish this?

My unix experience is average so if something is not clear about my question, feel free to ask.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Why don't you make it so that customers don't need customized files.

Comment: "When the filesize is different than it's source, it should overwrite. When it's the same filesize, it should skip the file." - surely the customers who have a customised file will be the ones that have a different filesize, so these are the ones that you should skip?

Comment: Correct! @Graeme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you changed the source code in one of your source files on one of your servers and want to port the fix onto other web sites, right? If you kept a copy of the orginial file (I always do when I don't know the project by heart), use your best asset: `diff`:

```
diff -Nau old/file new/file > file.patch
```

You will have a differential between the original and corrected source files, which you can patch all your servers with, through SSH, for instance:

```
# See what's to be done, no action
cat file.patch | ssh server "patch -d <directory> --dry-run"
# Apply the patch if all seems good
cat file.patch | ssh server "patch -d <directory>"
```

You might have to tweak the patch header if your unchanged copy is in a different directory than the corrected file. But basically, if both are in the same directory, `file.php` being the fixed file and `file.php.orig` the original, `cd`
to the root directory of your web site and run the `diff` command, e.g.:

```
cd /home/www/htdocs/www.mysite.tld
diff -Nau some/deep/dir/file.orig.php some/deep/dir/file.php > /tmp/file.patch
```

The from the root directory of the other web sites:

```
# See what's to be done, no action
patch -d /home/www/htdocs/www.my.other.site.tld --dry-run < /tmp/file.patch
# Apply the patch if all seems good
patch -d /home/www/htdocs/www.my.other.site.tld < /tmp/file.patch
```

Other useful argument is `-p`. Both `diff` and `patch` can work on a directory tree to apply fixes recursively. You can also build a more complex patch by concatenating them in one file. See `patch --help` and `diff --help` for more details on how to use them.

Comment: This is a great solution when you don't have modificated files! I'll upvote it anyway, can use this for later ^^

Comment: Actually, that's how git works, just doing it by hand. It is also simplest to put your [initial] master source under git and let it create patches for you everytime you fix something or simply change any source file. Deploying fixes is only a snap.

Comment: That's how I push my latest bugfixes trough aswell. However, this is a CMS made a couple of years ago without a framework nor did i used Git. In all new sites I do use git + cakephp :)!

Answer (score 1):

According to your original question verbatim, this is what you want, but see my comment below it. You may want to try just the `find` part on its own first to make sure you have the right files.

```
find /home -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -path */phpthumb/filename ! -size xxxx |
  xargs -t -n 1 cp /home/test/testuser/phpthumb/filename
```

For this to work as per my comment and replace the ones with the same size, just drop the `!`.

#### Update

Actually comparing MD5 sums is a better way to do this. It is more robust since it could be that one of your customised files happens to be the same size. You could try:

```
original_md5=$(md5sum /path/to/original | awk '{print $1}')
echo /home/*/*/phpthumb/filename |
  xargs md5sum |
  grep "^$original_md5" |
  awk '{print $2}' |
  xargs -t -n 1 cp /home/test/testuser/phpthumb/filename
```

This is to replace all files matching the original. To do it as per your  question verbatim, add the `-v` option to `grep`. Note also that neither of these answers will work if there are spaces in any of the search paths (just in case they have be added since you last question).

Comment: I will test it tonight! Will travel to my home soon. Will let you know if this did the trick.

Comment: I tested your second option since this is a little bit more failure-proof. However I get the following error: cp: missing destination file operand after `/home/jordy/public_html/test/testfoo.php', am i forgetting a parameter?

Comment: @Jordy, sounds like it isn't finding any matching files, have you got the right paths for the first `md5sum` and the `echo`?

Comment: My bad, it didn't copy the first line. Now the command runs fine! However, it does copy the file even when the MD5 mismatches.

Comment: @Jordy, it will do that if the `original_md5` variable is empty. It has to contain the MD5 sum of the file you are trying to replace. The first line (`original_md5=...`) should do this, but you have to replace `/path/to/original` with the path to an example of the file you are trying to replace.

Comment: This is what I got: original_md5=$(md5sum /home/jordy/public_html/dest/newfile.php | awk '{print $1}') echo /home/*/*/*/public_html/source/oldfile.php | xargs md5sum | grep "^$original_md5" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -t -n 1 cp /home/jordy/public_html/dest/newfile.php

Comment: @Jordy, if you run the first line, then do `echo "$original_md5"`, what do you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19845/discussion-between-jordy-and-graeme).